# Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1 when starting the kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka installed in my mac last year, which has many topics within the system. Now I upgrade the zookeeper and kafka to the latest version.

by running zookeeper, it is successful

```
zookeeper-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
```

Then a broker:

```
kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

however it comes up with the error

```
INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 0]: Error processing create topic request CreatableTopic(name='_confluent-license', numPartitions=1, replicationFactor=3, assignments=[], configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy', value='compact'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='min.insync.replicas', value='2')]) (kafka.server.AdminManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
```

How would I solve it?

Answer (score 6):

A Confluent enterprise license is stored in the `_confluent-command` topic. This topic is created by default and contains the license that corresponds to the license key supplied through the `confluent.license` property. So when you're starting the Kafka server it tries to create it with replication-factor of 3 but there is only 1 broker available so it failed.

Set `confluent.topic.replication.factor` property to `1` in `/usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties` file.

Comment: we shouldn't use this bundle without license ?

Comment: Seems like the default of a assume cluster of 3 is dumb.   Further, there are three separate replication factors to set:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62530484/562644

Answer (score 1):

@Pardeep 's answer worked for me, but for me there were more replication factors to set (I'm using Confluent 6.2.1):

```
confluent.balancer.topic.replication.factor=1
confluent.durability.topic.replication.factor=1
confluent.license.topic.replication.factor=1
confluent.tier.metadata.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
```

You can use `findstr` (on Windows) or `grep` (on Unix-based OS) to extract them all from the console output:

```
kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties | findstr "replication.factor"
```